# Merge two dataframe by partial match

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes with me
[image]

I want to merge both this  in search a way that values in df2 are in the same order as df1.

[image]

I was trying to use partial string match to merge the table but not successful as I am getting nan values for df2 values column.

Comment: kindly provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to manipulate the columns so that they match exactly, which should also make this easier to debug. Something like:

```
df2['Values'] = "data_value_" + df2['Values'].str.split("_").str[-1]
```

Then, you can do your merge.